# ReportMissingImports on Packages but Installed Successul (Python, M1 Mac)

Tags: python, import, streamlit, langchain

I have installed Streamlit, langchain and other packages successfully via `pip3 install` command but can not import it into the app due to the following error. Running all of this on Mac M1, Monterey, Python 2.7.18 (acc. to `python --version` command).

```
Requirement already satisfied: mdurl~=0.1 in **/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from markdown-it-py<3.0.0,>=2.2.0->rich>=10.11.0->streamlit**) (0.1.2)
```

Error Messages:

```
[{
    "resource": "/Users/------/VisualStudio Env/FirstLangChain_Project/App/app.py",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "code": {
        "value": "reportMissingImports",
        "target": {
            "$mid": 1,
            "path": "/microsoft/pyright/blob/main/docs/configuration.md",
            "scheme": "https",
            "authority": "github.com",
            "fragment": "reportMissingImports"
        }
    },
    "severity": 4,
    "message": "Import \"Streamlit\" could not be resolved",
    "source": "Pylance",
    "startLineNumber": 5,
    "startColumn": 8,
    "endLineNumber": 5,
    "endColumn": 17
}]

[{
    "resource": "/Users/------/VisualStudio Env/FirstLangChain_Project/App/app.py",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "code": {
        "value": "reportMissingImports",
        "target": {
            "$mid": 1,
            "path": "/microsoft/pyright/blob/main/docs/configuration.md",
            "scheme": "https",
            "authority": "github.com",
            "fragment": "reportMissingImports"
        }
    },
    "severity": 4,
    "message": "Import \"Langchain.llms\" could not be resolved",
    "source": "Pylance",
    "startLineNumber": 6,
    "startColumn": 6,
    "endLineNumber": 6,
    "endColumn": 20
}]
```